# role delegation module : how to fine-tune the 'edit-administer-users' permissions?

Tags: users

Using role delegation module , i allow a user say 'mat' with a 'site_admin' role to assign other users to a 'VIP_role'.

The problem is role delegation needs apparentely 'administer users permission' being selected for 'assign' actions to work.

When logging in with 'mat' credentials that's been set with 'administer users permission', it gives some back office links that i would like to restrict.

How could I restrict 'role delegate' to editing existing users and assign them roles ?

Comment: if all else fails, you could set up a series of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to defer those addresses to some other page based on the role of the current user

Comment: @Geoff could u provide an exemple on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it this way , unsetting menu links depending on role

```
  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136399/how-to-unset-admin-menu-links-programmatically
```

Answer (score 1):

The two modules you will need:

[Rules:](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

and [Context Redirect:](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_redirect)

> This module provides a Context reaction which redirects to a given
>   internal or external url if the context conditions are met.
>
> You could use this module to redirect users of specific roles to a
>   page of your choice, or redirect them based on a path in the site
>   (node/2, 'page.htm') to another page or external URL
>   (ht-p://www.google.com). Dozens of conditions can be cooked up with
>   Context and redirect users to where they need to go.

- set up a new rule, have it react on a url (based on whatever url you want to restrict)
- set a condition that the user be of the role for which you are trying to limit access
- set an action - presumably a redirect to a different page, or perhaps a custom page that tells them they don't have permission to view that url