# how to unset admin menu links programmatically?

Tags: hooks

how to unset admin menu links programmatically ?

I have created a module with this hook in it

```
function myModuleName_menu_link_alter(&$item)
{   

//  dpm($item['link_path']);
     if($item['link_path']=="/admin/config/people")
    {
     $item=FALSE;
    }
}
```

the link path

```
  "/admin/config/people"
```

is listed with dpm.

how can i remove it from the admin menu?

I have also tried with this hook

```
  function my module_menu_alter(&$items) {  

       // dpm($items['user/%user/cas']);
        unset($items['user/%user/cas']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i have done it

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 */

function people_manage_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['admin/people/create']['access callback'] = 'menu_people_access_callback';
   $items['admin/config/people/accounts']['access callback'] = 'menu_people_access_callback';
   $items['admin/config/user-interface']['access callback'] = 'menu_people_access_callback';


}


 function menu_people_access_callback($arg) {

       global $user;

        if(!in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {  
           return false ;
         }
      else{
         return true;
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

**hook_menu_alter** is want you are looking for. The usage is exactly the same as your example, just don't forget to clear the caches afterwards.

Cheers!

Comment: well it does not work . could it be something to do with the translation? a different menu generated? i am using a french back office

Comment: I seriously doubt it. I successfully unset _admin/dashboard_ and _user/%user/edit_ if you worry for the wildcard operator. Should work with any other menu item.

You did flush the cacehs right?